# What is electrodialysis and is electrolysis prevented or suppressed?

Tags: water, ions

Recently, I was introduced to a method of desalinization called electrodialysis in which a current was applied to salt water in such a way that the positive and negative were separated and drawn through membranes, leaving less salty water in between.  how do the membranes facilitate a one-way flow of ions?

Also, this method sounds a lot like the electrolysis.  How is electrolysis prevented or suppressed?

Comment: Could [electrodialysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodialysis) be the method you are searching for?

Comment: Yes the name I was looking for is electrodialysis